# Pass Craft Instance to A Vendor PHP File

Tags: plugin-development

I created my own class file that I include in one of my Craft Services files. Is there any way I can access the craft instance inside of this file?

For example, inside my Craft service I create a new instance of my class like:

$wally = new Wally();

Inside of the actual Wally class file, I'd like to be able to create a variable in my constructor that gives me access to stuff like this:

```
craft()->elements->getCriteria(ElementType::Entry);
```

For further clarification:

```
class Wally {
   function __construct($craftInstance) {
      $this->craft = $craftInstance;
   }
}
```

If it sounds like I don't know what I'm doing, I probably don't. Any help would be appreciated. Using Craft 2.6 btw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to pass anything in there.

The function `craft()` is just a public function that returns the static app. It does not matter if you call it inside a plugin or somewhere else.

```
namespace Craft; //<----- added namespace
class Wally {
   function __construct() {
      $criteria = craft()->elements->getCriteria(ElementType::Entry);
   }
}
```

If you don't want to be in the same namespace you can do

```
class Wally {
   function __construct() {
      $criteria = \Craft\craft()->elements->getCriteria(\Craft\ElementType::Entry);
   }
}
```

If you really want to save the app in an extra variable for whatever reasons you would do

```
new Wally(craft());
```

Comment: Well, the particular reason is I wrote some Hackalicious code that is going to have to wait to be refactored. This will definitely work! Thanks a lot.

Comment: Just a quick question. Wouldnt $criteria be, $this->criteria in the constructor? Just checking if this was intentional or not.

Comment: It depends what you are going to do. I don't know what you want or achieve.

Comment: Well, I ended up making an external class in a vendor file to handle a ton of the programming logic required in one of my Services files. The reason behind this was because I didn't want to clutter up my Service class file with a bunch of looping and traversal stuff. So basically, I queried my entry in the service, and ended up just passing that response off into my vendor class. However, I hit somewhat of a wall when I realized I needed to perform image transforms inside this class. I guess I was just trying to stay organized, but probably didnt go about it in the right way.

Comment: Dont really know why I didnt just do it all in the Service.

Comment: Maybe you could show me your class because generally speeking you would do it the same way like in the service no matter where your code is.in craft 3 everything is in the vendor folder

Comment: Rofl. I am actually on the train rewriting it right now. I can share it in a bit. What time is it in Germany right now?

Comment: 13:18 so my day ends in about 11 hours. Take your time, I don't have anything else to do today

Comment: https://gist.github.com/DZuz14/9d2c7869c2ecf7c25feec478417f6563

Comment: Before I say something else... Are you familiar with eager loading? Because there are quite a few (to be honest more than a few) parts in your code that is done by Craft. I could easily reduce your class by 80% which means less code, less queries and a better performance

Comment: Nope I am not. That would be epic. Care to hop in a chat?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74808/discussion-between-robin-schambach-and-daniel-zuzevich).